# firebase cloud write data with a "key" paramter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am learning Cloud Functions for Firebase. What I want is pass the key and value in the URL parameters, like:

```
https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net/addMessageSet?text=goodboy&key=testKey
```

And then in the Realtime Database set a `testKey:goodboy`.

I know use `push()` will generate a unique key (if i understood correctly) but I'd like use my own key each time. I am not sure if `set()` works.

My problem is `push({originalKey:original})` doesn't work as expected. It writes:

```
originalKey: goodboy
```

Where `originalKey` is just key not the parameter from the URL. Is this possible or any other solutions?

The code is like below:

```
exports.addMessageSet = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const original = req.query.text;
    const originalKey = req.query.key;
    admin.database().ref('/messages/').push({originalKey:original}).then(snapshot => {
        console.log('goodboy', original, originalKey);
        res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a key you're generating without firebase generating another you need to use set with your key in the path

```
admin.database().ref('/messages/' + originalKey).set(original).then(snapshot => { });
// if originalKey is not a string use String(originalKey)
```

You said about `originalKey` not beeing a url, but everything in firebase if url based, like this you're doing

```
myDB
|_ messages
   |_ originalKey: original
```

and not

```
myDB > messages > originalKey > original
```

If you need another key after the `messages` node i recomend using a date UNIX number, momentJS is good to handle this.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Using push() will indeed generate a unique key. You will need to use either set() or update().

Note that using set() will overwrite the data at the specified location including any child nodes.